# Como retonar todas las columnas de una consulta JOIN en ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, consola, activerecord

Ahora necesito hacer lo siguiente

Tengo 2 tablas:

- user
- package

Resulta que estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
np = Package.joins(:user).where(["children_price is not :cp or children_foreigner_price is not :cfp", {cp: nil, cfp: nil}])
```

Esta consulta funciona casi perfectamente es solo que solo me esta retornando los campos de la tabla Package y no las de User...

La consulta hace esto:

```
SELECT `packages`.* FROM `packages` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `packages`.`user_id` WHERE (children_price is not NULL or children_foreigner_price is not NULL)
```

Me dijeron que le agregara un select al final y asi quedo la consulta:

```
np = Package.joins(:user).where(["children_price is not :cp or children_foreigner_price is not :cfp", {cp: nil, cfp: nil}]).select('users.*')
```

El problema es que no me retorna toda la información solamente aquello que tienen en común paquetes y usuarios...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que yo necesito es algo como esto

Que retorne todos los parameros

```
Select <Todas las columnas de paquetes>, <Todas las columnas de user> fron packages inner join users;
```

O en su defecto:

```
select p.id, u.name from FROM `packages` p INNER JOIN `users` u where p.children_price is not NULL or p.children_foreigner_price is not NULL
```

Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es solo el nombre, podrías agregar `select('packages.*, users.name')` y en caso que ya tengas un campo `name` para packages, agrega un alias como `select('packages.*, users.name AS user_name')`.  Luego, lo puedes leer en tu instancia con `package.user_name`.
En caso de que requieras más de un campo desde packages, te recomendaría que en vez de seguir agregando columnas a tu select uses `includes(:user)` lo cual realizará 2 consultas, una para packages y otra para todos los registros de users relacionados con los packages retornados que quedarán guardados en memoria hasta que los requieras. Para este caso, deberías acceder el valor con `package.user.name`.
¿Podrías usar algo como lo que mencionas de `Select <Todas las columnas de paquetes>, <Todas las columnas de user>`? si, pero perdería todo el sentido de la funcionalidad ORM que te entrega ActiveRecord, aparte que sería un problema mantenerlo a largo plazo.

Comment: Hola... he hecho lo que me has dicho y agregar un select al final ...
y así quedo la consulta: np = Package.joins(:user).where(["children_price is not :cp or children_foreigner_price is not :cfp", {cp: nil, cfp: nil}]).select('users.*') el problema es que solo me retorna los datos que tienen en común ambas tablas y yo los necesito todos.

Comment: Y ahora si imprimo:
np[1].user.email me retorna el correo exitosamente... el problema es que no se como hago para que me retorne en la consulta?

Comment: @AndresFelipeHernandez pero el select que pusiste no es el mismo que puse en mi respuesta. Si necesitas todos los packages, incluso los que no tienen user, no te sirve `joins`, debes hacer un `left_outer_joins(:user)`. Respecto a retornar todo en una consulta, vuelvo a insistir en la utilidad del ORM, ¿que tan buena es tu razón para querer retornar todo en una misma query?. Por último, [evita usar pantallazos en S.O.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/213), mejor que copies y pegues el resultado de tu terminal. Saludos

Comment: la versión de rails que tiene mi maquina no soporta esa sentencia... entonces procedi a descargar las 2 tablas en archivo plano y luego con un script de python juntarlas manualmente. Gracias por tu ayuda.